# Passing string values from one form to another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing variable between winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247807/passing-variable-between-winforms)

I have two forms one called Form1 the other called TicTacToeMainMenu.

In TicTacToeMainMenu I have created two variables

```
string Player1;
string Player2;
```

I have assigned two text fields to both variables.

```
pvpPl1.Text = Player1;
pvpPl2.Text = Player2;
```

I would like to grab the string values from TicTacToeMainMenu and use them in another form, Form1 how would I do this?

Comment: you could just pass the values over the constructor of Form1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247807/passing-variable-between-winforms

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280579/how-do-i-pass-a-value-from-a-child-back-to-the-parent-form

Comment: Which form is your main form?

Comment: From your question, I immediately assumed both forms are showing when you want this to occur. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: One form is hidden at the current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are instantiating form1 from the TicTacToeMainMenu form, then you can pass the variable into the constructor of Form1:

```
public string Player1 { get; set; }
public string Player2 { get; set; }
public Form1(string player1, string player2)
{

    InitializeComponent();

    this.Player1 = player1;
    this.Player2 = player2;

}
```

Then to call it, you simply:

```
Form1 f = new Form1(Player1, Player2);
f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: You can't then design the form in the Visual Studio designer. Not everyone cares about that, but I thought I'd point it out anyway. The alternative is to have properties that are intended to be set during form initialization.

Comment: @siride True, but you could leave a default constructor in there as well if you wanted.