# send TextBox Values from FormB to a datagridView in FormA

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox

I have to send the value of 2 TextBoxes from FormB when I clic on the "validate buton" to the datagridView in FormA;this is what I try to code:

FormB:

```
namespace RibbonDemo.Fichier
{
    public partial class NvFamillImmo : Form
    {
        public event BetweenFormEventHandler BetweenForm;
        SqlDataAdapter dr;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string req;

        public NvFamillImmo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            affich();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //the validate buton
        {

            if (BetweenForm != null)
                BetweenForm(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);

        }

        private void fillByToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.amortissementFiscalTableAdapter.FillBy(this.mainDataSet.amortissementFiscal);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and this is FormA:

```
namespace RibbonDemo.Fichier
{
    public delegate void BetweenFormEventHandler(string txtbox1value, string txtbox2value);
    public partial class FammileImm : Form
    {

        private NvFamillImmo nvFamillImmo;
        public FammileImm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {

            NvFamillImmo frm2 = new NvFamillImmo();
            frm2.BetweenForm += frm2_BetweenForm;
            frm2.ShowDialog();
        }


        void frm2_BetweenForm(string txtbox1value, string txtbox2value)
        {

        //dataGridView1.Refresh();

        String str1 = nvFamillImmo.textBox1.Text.ToString();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = str1;

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:I filled the method frm2_BetwwenForm but now I get a problem in reference
thanks for Help

Comment: I think you are missing the part where you have to add a new row with the values that you want to the datagridview. That would we in the frm2_BetweenForm(...)

Comment: thanks fabricio I have edited the frm2_Between.. method like that:

Comment: void frm2_BetweenForm(string txtbox1value, string txtbox2value)
        {            
            String str1 = nvFamillImmo.textBox1.Text.ToString(); //problem in this line
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = str1;
        } but I get a problem in reference

Comment: Try to add this line before.. this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing variable between winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247807/passing-variable-between-winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Need to create event for that. you can create properties in second form where you want to send value from existing form. for example if you have two forms **FormA** and **FormB** then **FormB** should contains properties like `Value1` and `Value2`.

```
//FormB
public class FormB :Form
{
    public string Value1{get; set;}
    public string Value2{get; set;}
}
```

Now you can assign value into both properties from **FormA**.

```
//FormA
public void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormB myForm = new FormB();
    myForm.Value1 = textBox1.Text;
    myForm.Value2 = textBox1.Text;
    myForm.Show();
}
```

Then you can get both textboxes value into **FormB**. You can handle value into **Form Load** event

```
//FormB
public void FormB_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fromTextBox1 = this.Value1;
    string formTextBox2 = this.Value2;
}
```

---

If the **FormB** is already loaded and want to send value from **FormA** then create a method `UpdateValues()` and modify the properties to call that method.

```
//FormB
string _value1 = string.Empty;
public string Value1
{
    get { return _value1; }
    set {
        _value1 = value;
        UpdateValues();
    }
}
string _value2 = string.Empty;
public string Value1
{
    get { return _value2; }
    set {
        _value2 = value;
        UpdateValues();
    }
}
private void UpdateValues()
{
    string fromTextBox1 = this.Value1;
    string fromTextBox2 = this.Value2;
}
```

and Assign the values in `FormB.Value1` and `FormB.Value2` properties from **FormA**.

```
//FormA
FormB myForm = new FormB();
public void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (myForm != null && myForm.IsDisposed == false)
    {
        myForm.Value1 = textBox1.Text;
        myForm.Value2 = textBox1.Text;        
    }
}
```

When the value is updated from **FormA** then **UpdateValues()** method will be called.

Comment: thanks shell and other guys it works :D I have an other question please how can I send the values from formB to forma without creating a new instance? thanks again

Comment: @Lina is your FormB is displaying in `Modal Dialog`? I mean I do you show the `FormB`. using `Show()` method or `ShowDialog()` method?

Comment: FormB it's a Form I use the Show() method to display the Form :)

Comment: You can handle `FormClosing` event of `FormB` in `FormA`. Where you can get back value from `Value1` and `Value2` properties. Do you call `FormB` from `FormA`?

Comment: yes I have called FormB from FormA then I put this.Close() to FormA after the call of FormB and the formA dosen't disappear :/

Comment: thanks Shell now it works correctly I worked with the incorrect button now every thing is working fine :D thanks again for your Help

Comment: great @Lina, Did you got back values from `FormB` to `FormA`?

Comment: yes I get the values in theDataGridView using your method thanks very much :D