# How to pass and read parameters in a winform in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I've read some other questions but I couldn't figure out how to solve my problem.

I have two forms in my application. `frmMain` and `frmAdd`. I want to open `frmAdd` from main form with a parameter to use in `frmAdd`.The below code i have tried

**frmMain**

```
frmAdd frm= new frmAdd("A");
frm.ShowDialog();
```

**frmAdd**

```
if (parameter=="A")
   //Do this
else if(parameter=="B")
  //Do that
```

How can I make it work?

```
public partial class frmAdd : Form
{
   public frmAdd() //Should I add somthing here?
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

Comment: "read some other questions " - not clear what other question you've found, linked [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247807/passing-variable-between-winforms) looks pretty close to what you want - read and comment what you don't understand (rather than simply stating [clinically tested](http://xkcd.com/1096/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add parameterized constructor so that the form could be created with parameter and use this() to call the parameterless constructor

```
public partial class frmAdd : Form
    {
        public frmAdd() //Should I add somthing here?
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public frmAdd(string str) : this()
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: It works but `InitializeComponent();` has to be included in `public frmAdd(string str) : this()`

Comment: @AlexJolig, nope, `this()` part will ensure parameterless constructor will be called first, which contains `InitializeComponents()` already. Removing parameterless constructor is bad idea.

Comment: @Sinatr But my form has no controls and `form_load` event when showing up untill I added `InitializeComponents()` to `public frmAdd(string str) : this()`

Comment: You've made a mistake somewhere: either you forgot to add `this()` to a new constructor with parameter or you removed `InitializeComponents()` from parameterless constructor.