# How to send a serialport as a parameter from one window form to another window form?

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I am working with serialport. I have two window forms and I need to use the serialPort in both forms. How can I send serialport from one form to the 2nd one as a parameter? My code looks like:

```
namespace SimpleSerial
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Form2 pp = new Form2()

      public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
        pp.ShowDialog();
      }
      private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        serialPort1.PortName = "Com3";       
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
```

and code for 2nd Form:

```
namespace SimpleSerial
{
  public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
      public Form2()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
          getAvailablePorts();
        }
```

Comment: You havent shown your serial variable, you can have it as a property on form2, that you can pick up from form1, or, have form1 subscribe to a "selected" event .. choice is yours see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7e9f80c-5144-4ad9-aa5e-7803363ae0cd/passing-variables-between-forms?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Thanks . Now I have updated my question. you can see the serial variable

Comment: that code is not viable - my URL link still stands as the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variable between winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247807/passing-variable-between-winforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create parameterized constructor in `form2` as

```
public Form2(SerialPort SP)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     serialPort2 = SP;
}
```

now pass `SerialPort` from form1 to form2 as

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(serialPort1);
frm.ShowDialog();
```

so on `form2` `serialPort2`  will get all the properties of `form1` `serialPort1`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Port through the constructor of your Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
  private readonly SerialPort Port;
  public Form2(SerialPort Port)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Port = Port;
  }
}
```

Now you are able to use the Port in your Form2.

During creation of the Form2 in your Form1, pass the Port like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private SerialPort Port;
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Port = new SerialPort();
    Form2 pp = new Form2(Port);
    pp.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

Note that objects are passed by reference in C#. That means, if you close the Port in Form1 for example, the Port in Form2 is also closed (because its the same object)!