# C# Open form2 at specific record from DataGridView click

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview on form1 (MainMenu) and I want to double click and open form2 (TrainingRecord) at the record I selected on form 1 (MainMenu).

This is my existing code which is missing the datagridview selection code which goes something like this:

```
// StaffDataGridSelect.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString()

this.TrainingDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

It's all bound to a database but I just can't figure out how to open the new form on that particular record. Once I can open the form I can navigate and edit records using the default form navigation buttons but I want to be able to open it at a specific record.

```
private void TrainingDataGridView_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.TrainingDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    Form TrainingRecord = new TrainingRecord();

    TrainingRecord.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    TrainingRecord.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    TrainingRecord.Show();
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. I'm right you have a grid and if user double click a new Form is shown exactly on the coordinates where he clicked?

Comment: Do you want to [pass data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247807/passing-variable-between-winforms) to TrainingRecord?

Comment: See my 2 form project and following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net